# How can I set up a "USB proxy" for /dev/ttyUSB0 over the network?

Tags: usb-device, streams, ttyusb

I have a device under test (DUT) and I measure its power usage the using a [Power Analyzer Datalogger](https://web.archive.org/web/20160102131333/http://www.extech.com/instruments/product.asp?catid=14&prodid=206) using the data from `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

The problem is that the DUT is now remotely from the workstation I used to gather data with, but in the same network, I need to use a 2nd PC which is directly  connected via USB to the Power Analyzer as a sort of USB proxy and ssh to create a kind of symbolic link on the measuring machine of the USB of the "proxy" machine.

[image]

Given the above diagram how can the 1<sup>st</sup> PC access `/dev/ttyUSB0` of the 2<sup>nd</sup> PC which is directly connected, in a way that a program reading the stream from the 1<sup>st</sup> PC will not notice the difference?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`socat` might work here.

On the 2nd PC you could let `socat` listen for data on `/dev/ttyUSB0` and serve it to a tcp port, e.g:

```
socat /dev/ttyUSB0,raw,echo=0 tcp-listen:8888,reuseaddr
```

Then on 1st PC you can connect to 2nd PC with socat and provide the data on a pseudo terminal `/dev/ttyVUSB0` for your application:

```
socat PTY,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyVUSB0 tcp:<ip_of_pc2>:8888
```

This isn't tested and `socat` supports many options, so tweaking may be needed.

Comment: Thanks!  Test environment in docker container on laptop -> SSH tunnel -> PC in clean-room -> AVR programmer and FTDI logger in clean-room

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of `ser2net` and `socat`. For example, I have a robot connected to a raspberry pi through a serial port. The raspberry pi is connected to my local network (equivalent to your 2nd PC). And my laptop is connected to the same local network (equivalent to your 1st PC). Then I use ser2net to forward the serial port via TCP from the 2nd PC, and create a proxy serial device file using `socat` on the 1st PC.

This setup may work for you as well. Proposed solution:

**Step 1: Install ser2net package on your 2nd PC (following your diagram)**

`sudo apt-get install ser2net`

ser2net listens to a TCP port and is able to pipe data to and from a serial port via the TCP port. You can set up which serial ports you want to create "proxies" for via its configuration file `/etc/ser2net.conf`.

**Step 2: configure ser2net in the 2nd PC**

For example, if you have a device connected at `/dev/ttyACM0` with baudrate `115200` and want to serve it from localhost port 3333, then you can add the following line to `/etc/ser2net.conf`

`3333:raw:0:/dev/ttyACM0:115200,remctl`

Having created the configuration file, then either start ser2net by running on the second PC:

`ser2net`

or (if it's already running, then just restart it as below)

`/etc/init.d/ser2net restart`

One important thing here is the remctl option. It allows the client side (1st PC in your diagram) to connect to the device and choose the serial connection options freely. I think this way the serial communication is completely transparent from the data collection workspace perspective. See [more details here](https://github.com/qchats/ser2net/blob/master/ser2net.conf).

**Step 3: Set up proxy serial device file on the data collection workstation (1st PC)**

(if you don't have socat, then `sudo apt-get install socat`)

Finally, in a terminal on the 1st PC let `socat` create a proxy serial port that will listen from the tcp port:

`socat pty,link=$HOME/MyProxySerialPort,waitslave tcp:$ip:$port,forever,reuseaddr,keepalive`

Where, in this example `ip=<2nd-PC-IP-address>` and `port=3333` (or whatever you chose when setting up `/etc/ser2net.conf` on the 2nd PC).

**Step 4: Connect to MyProxySerialPort**

Now you should be able to open a serial connection normally to the device located at `$HOME/MyProxySerialPort` on the 1st PC.

This blog post has some more information about this setup too: http://techtinkering.com/2013/04/02/connecting-to-a-remote-serial-port-over-tcpip/

Comment: very detailed answer +1

Answer (score 2):

In linux kernels which are using a symbolic link from */dev/bus/usb/BUS_ID/DEV_ID* to */dev/char/MAJOR:MINOR* **socat** cannot open such devices due to an inappropriate IOCTL error!
So this approach does not seem to work directly on USB devices.

I tried **usbip** which is a closer implementation but only supported on older kernels.

Since my solution was about card readers connected via pcsc-lite there was a better solution using the environment variable for **libpcsclite** clients.

```
export PCSCLITE_CSOCK_NAME=$HOME/.pcscd.comm
```

This way a diferent unix domain socket can be specified.
And this one can be forwarded to the card reader socket on a remote host using **socat**:

**Run this on the host to replace the card reader**

```
socat tcp:$CARD_READER_HOST:8888 UNIX-LISTEN:$PCSCLITE_CSOCK_NAME,fork
```

**run this on the CARD_READER_HOST host with the pcsc card reader connected**

```
socat UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/pcscd/pcscd.comm tcp-listen:8888,fork,reuseaddr
```

Comment: Hi and welcome :).  This is interesting information but it does not relate to the question about `/dev/ttyUSB0`, or a power analyzer which does not use PCSCLITE.  If you would like to post this information, it would be better as a separate question.  You are permitted and encouraged to post on-topic questions for which you have an immediate follow-on answer.

Comment: I tried it and the relevant information was that the proposed answer DID NOT work! I think this info requires sharing.

The rest is truly not directly relevant but offers a different approach for related problems.

Comment: Would this be because of the `:` character in the path? The socat man page, section "ADDRESS SPECIFICATIONS", has a paragraph about how to escape characters (v1.5.0 onwards).

Comment: interesting point, but the project has been canned so no way to check it anymore :(