# Pass a Linux virtual USB device into Windows host

Tags: usb, emulation

The goal is:

1. Create a virtual **USB** web camera on Linux machine / Guest VM.
2. Connect it to a Windows machine / host.

**Unfortunately, there is no way of using any hardware connections.**

The plan is:

1. Use Linux as a simulated virtual USB device as shown in [this tutorial](http://www.davidhunt.ie/raspberry-pi-zero-with-pi-camera-as-usb-webcam/). They use a Raspberry Pi with a real hardware camera connected to the Pi, but the idea is to use the software part and feed virtually crafted frames instead of using a real one.
2. Now the VM should behave as a **real hardware USB web camera**, when it is connected to a USB master.

So, there are three ways, as far as I'm concerned (which both lead to a dead end with my level of knowledge):

1. Somehow connect the VM as a USB slave to the Windows host machine. It seems impossible, since there will be a need of faking a USB connection on the physical USB bus.
2. Create another VM, which will serve as a buffer. Somehow connect the WebCam VM to the Buffer VM and then use **USBIP** protocol to pass it into the Windows Host.
3. Somehow **virtually** connect a USB host device to the WebCam VM, which should make the VM behave as a USB slave, and proxy everything via **USBIP**.

2 and 3 really are really similar and seem like the only way out. But I don't know if it could be done without writing any low-level driver stuff.

Help, please? I might be overcomplicating, but there seems to be no way to emulate a USB camera connection on Windows except for writing your own driver, which is exactly the thing I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Does it have to be USB? You may connect the USB to a TCP port with `socat`, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/201763/123460 - then just use the NAT between host and guest. Still give out the raw stream.

Comment: @FelixJN yeah, I wish I needed the raw stream itself, man. I really wish. Windows needs to see it as a valid USB video device and receive the stream this way.